# OWL API OWLAnnotation.getProperty() is inconsistent

Tags: owl, owl-api

I would like to have a full property name, with prefix. I go through annotation list and print the annotation values:

```
OWLAnnotation anno = ...;
String property = anno.getProperty().toString();
```

Here is what I get - sometimes property shows up with a prefix, sometimes without. I need it to be with prefixes all the time...

```
Annotation(rdfs:label "influenza"^^xsd:string)
Annotation(<http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasExactSynonym> "Influenza with non-respiratory manifestation (disorder)"^^xsd:string)
```

Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: you have to use a renderer for the OWL objects, i.e. an instance of this [interface](https://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/io/OWLObjectRenderer.html)

Comment: And regarding your examples, OWL API indeed has the built-in prefix mappings for RDFS, RDF, XSD, OWL etc. but indeed not for the second annotation with a custom URI namespace

Comment: Use the [SimpleRenderer](https://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/util/SimpleRenderer.html) and plugin your prefix declarations.

Comment: Thank you, AKSW. This is what I did: OWLObjectRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer(); System.out.println(renderer.render(anno.getProperty()).toStr‌​ing()); Still shows as rdfs:label. I need it with a prefix, because I need to compare with a string that comes from another program...  I guess I need to use ShortFormProvider? But which one?

Comment: Indeed you need a shortformprovider. the `DefaultPrefixManager` would be one. In any case, you have to add the prefix declarations, otherwise, it can't know which namespace to use with which prefix. I hope this is clear.

Comment: DefaultPrefixManager pm = new DefaultPrefixManager("http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#");
System.out.print(pm.getShortForm(anno.getProperty()));
Still rdfs:label...

Comment: Sorry, but you want to get what? The prefixed form, or the full URI? For the full URI, always call `toStringID()` to avoid the usage of a renderer.

Comment: I want to use anno.getProperty() and get String property: "http://www.w3.or
g/2000/01/rdf-schema#label" (editor cutting h-t-t-p-:-/-/-w-w-w., had to add some dashes, otherwise it would disappear)

Comment: `toStringID()` is the method that you have to call for each OWL entity to ensure that you're getting the full URI/IRI

Comment: Excellent! This worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

anno.getProperty().getIRI().toQuotedString()

Will give toy the guillemot wrapped version.